# JS, jquery - split не хочет работать внутри each

Tags: javascript, jquery

Все должно быть максимально просто, но я не понимаю почему у меня не работает.

Есть список:

```html
<ul>
<li>1 BRAISAZ-BOUCHET Justine FRA 1996 11:00:30</li>
<li>2 LUNDER Emma CAN 1991 11:01:00</li>
<li>3 HAUSER Lisa Theresa AUT 1993 11:01:30</li>
</ul>
```

Нужно каждый li разбить на массив, произвести несколько манипуляций с массивом, снова в строку, и вернуть.

Чтобы я ни делал, мне выдает одну и ту же ошибку "$(...).split is not a function"

```
$("li").each(function(index) {
    var arr = $(this).split(" ");
    return arr.join(" ");
});
```

Comment: Сплитить содержимое надо

Comment: `$(this)` - это не строка, у него нет метода `.split()`

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("li").each(function() {
  let arr = $(this).text().split(" ");
  let chtoToDelaetsjaArr = arr.map(el => el + ' !!! ');
  $(this).text(chtoToDelaetsjaArr.join(" "));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1 BRAISAZ-BOUCHET Justine FRA 1996 11:00:30</li>
  <li>2 LUNDER Emma CAN 1991 11:01:00</li>
  <li>3 HAUSER Lisa Theresa AUT 1993 11:01:30</li>
</ul>
```